# touch transparent area of spritenode

Tags: sprite-kit

I have a few button with amorphous look. (the Rect of the buttons are intersecting)  First I evaluated the BeganTouch in the GameScene. Then I get several touches.

Since I have in my buttons still child nodes, they have swallowed the touchs. Ok, I have made with the help of here a subclass of the SpriteNodes and processed the touch inside the subclass. Now I have the problem that the first button does not pass the touch to the underlying sprites.

But now I would like top ignore the transparent areas of the buttons, how can I do that?

I have read that one can work with physicsbody, I have tried, gravitiy = 0 but since I move and scale the buttons via actions there were violent effects.

Why can I check for the alpha in the touch location and pass the touch to the next sprite.

by the way: how can I get a reference to the view? to get the global loc.
let loc = touch.location(in: view)

with the global touch location I could check all sprites under this point for the alpha!

Comment: no, I did it in a  subcluss like in the other answer. thats working fine. but when the user touch the first button in a transparent area, the button2 behind the button1 didn't get a touch event. therefore I need the global loc to get all other buttons touched and check for non transparent pixel.

Comment: you need to evaluate the texture to make sure you are not hitting these transparent spots.  But the real question is, WHY?  Do you have so much transparent area that you can discern it with a finger touch?

Comment: normal the user would touch the optical center of the button, but german creative agencies and there first class automobile clients looks for not touchable areas to stress the programmer.

Comment: I could see it being a factor on devices that allow for pixel perfect precision, but for a touch screen that relies on finger pressing, it actually offers a better user experience to extend the button outside of the box because you can't press with pixel perfect precision with a finger.  But anyway like I said, you know the position of the touch on the button, so just check the texture at that position to determine if it is transparent or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, it's simple, all buttons are from the same subclass. this subclass delegates to an method in the GameScene. here I can check with

allNodes = nodes(at: globalLocation)

now I can check for the name of the node, calculate the point of the pixel inside each node and get the alpha value.

thanxs all

Comment: How do you calculate the alpha value of the touched point of a sprite? Is Core Graphics fast enough for that? Is there a faster way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

you can try passing the touch to it's parent (presumably the scene) from your subclass.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if let touch = touches.first as UITouch! {

        //handle whatever code you want your subclass to do
        ... 

        //pass the touch event to the parent
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }
}
```

and then in your scene, cycle through the your buttons (in this example I have the buttons in a button array)

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if let touch = touches.first as UITouch! {

        let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)

        for button in buttons {

            if button.contains(touchLocation) {
                //handle all other buttons
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

although this seems a little redundant to do the touches in two different locations. @Knight0fDragon is correct, it seems odd to have a button have transparent areas.

Comment: I think you meant to call `parent?.touchesBegan` not `super.touchesBegan`